# How to connect Google Domain to AWS ELB url

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have recently uploaded a server with node js in my AWS environment and added a HTTPS listener in my load balancer. Also generated a certificate using ACM(AWS certificate manager) for my google domain and added it in HTTPS Listener. Added .ebextensions folder to upgrade Websocket in Proxy server. I have no Idea how can I connect my domain to my beanstalk app which url is something like "myapp.region.elasticbeanstalk.com" so that I can connect as "**wss**://MyGoogleDomain.com". Can you guys help me? I am new to this.

Comment: Slightly confusing what you're asking for. Your google domain is just the domain name? And you want your AWS env assigned to the domain? I assume your node is on EC2?

Answer (score 0):

Steps to host your domain on AWS EC2 :

- Create a hosted zone in route53
- Create record set with Alias name(your beanstalk URL)
- In your domain hosted zone you will get some Nameservers
- Copy those one by one and paste them google domain settings

You should be able to connect now. :)

Caution : Route53 charges some fraction of money every month even if you are on free tier